# How to make scrollable overlay

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to achieve something like the image below. The goal is to have an overlay with an editText that that can scroll and hide the content under it. I'm not sure how to do this with Java or XML. The image on the left is the desired initial screen and the second screen is when the scrollView overlays the content, and a header appears.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might achieve that with a [Collapsing Toolbar](https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/backdrop"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
      android:src="@drawable/appbar_image" />

  <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: You should use a CoordinatorLayout as the parent of your whole layout. The first child of it should be a scrollable view. In your case, I could be a scrollview that contains your edittext. The second child of the CoordinatorLayout should be CollapsingToolbarLayout. It is described in the previous link I sent in my answer.